# How to display the populate values from the previous input fields using Jet Form Builder?

Tags: wordpress, jet-engine

I'm using jetformbuilder wordpress plugin to design a more complex multi-step form. I want to populate the fields on the last step to see the overview of the fields that user has input.

I did follow the instructions here in this guide [JetFormBuilder Macros](https://jetformbuilder.com/features/adding-global-form-macros-to-buttons-block-and-fields/) using `<!-- JFB_FIELD::name -->`. But when I try to test, it doesn't seem to show. Is there a proper way how to use this or why is it not showing?

I'm using `Version 1.5.4` for the JetFormBuilder though but `<!-- JFB_FIELD::name -->` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Hi not sure if you still need this but you just need to remove the dashes:

In HTML the dashes acts as a comment meaning it is not displayed in the browser

`<!-- JFB_FIELD::name -->`

Change to:

`<!JFB_FIELD::name>`

Hope that helps...

I have found an issue though, not sure if it is because I am using the wrong block but the block will display an error and try and recover if you try to recover it will add the double dashes again and the information on the front page will disappear.